# Visual Studio C++ Source file accessible despite no #include?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, include

I tried searching for similar questions, but I found this difficult to phrase, so I apologize if this is a duplicate.

I'm messing around with Visual Studio 2013, writing a pretty simple C++ Console Application. Without going into too much details, I have three files - file1.h, file2.cpp, and main.cpp

- file1.h contains the interface for a class
- file2.cpp includes file1.h and contains the class's member functions
- main.cpp includes file1.h

So upon executing my program, I was very surprised that main.cpp had access to the functions inside file2.cpp, despite main only including file1.h.

I don't think this is the best way to go about organizing the code, but it piqued my curiosity - how is it that I can access functions contained in file2.cpp from main.cpp, despite the fact that only file1.h is included in main.cpp?

It would make sense to me if I had file2.cpp included in file1.h, but I don't.

**I'm just curious how/why this works. Thanks for reading.**

EDIT: If I've omitted any critical information, I apologize - just let me know and I can clarify.

Comment: You said it yourself. `file1.h` contains the interface. The definitions of those functions are available through linking, but the declarations are right there.

Comment: And that interface is included in main.cpp. However, main.cpp still has access to the functions defined in file2.cpp, despite the fact that file2.cpp is not included in file1.h nor main.cpp. Is this just some compiler magic that automatically gives main.cpp access to those member functions contained within file2.cpp?

Comment: @user3730915 you must distinguish between definition and declaration. Declaration is all you need to create objects or calling methods or functions. As long as you have the declarations in the *.h, that's all you need.

Comment: @jsantander Cool! So as long as the declaration is included in main.cpp, I have access to the definitions automagically, even though those definitions themselves aren't included in any file?

Comment: @user3730915 You do need the definition at link time. At link time you will need the `file2.o` (but not the `file2.cpp`) and the `main.o` to be linked (+ other libraries and stuff you *included*) to be provided to the linker in order to produce the final executable or library.

Answer (score 1):

You can compile main.cpp and file2.cpp separately. The file1.h will be compiled with both of them. You will get two object files, possibly main.o and file2.o, and main.o will be linked against file2.o(and may be against other libraries) to form the executable. This method is called separate compilation and is used very often, so it should be a good way to organise your code... For example this is why you don't need to recompile the standard library every time you use one of it's objects or functions.

Comment: I see, that's pretty neat. I guess the final clarification is - main.o and file2.o... what linked them together? I didn't specify that anywhere or nothing... so I'm guessing it's just recognizing "Oh, main.cpp includes file1.h, and file2.cpp contains file1.h's definitions (and file1.h is included in file2.cpp, of course), so lets link main.o and file2.o together."? Also - I appreciate your detailed answer. I would upvote you were this not my first question ^_^ - I need some more points first.

Comment: No, it's the IDE(VS) knowing that those two .cpp files belong to the same project, and links them together... If you only had a compiler and a linker then you would have to specify it manually...

Comment: There we go - I completely understand now. Thanks so much.